# Find series of following numbers

Tags: algorithm

I have a simple algorithmic problem, that I'm somehow struggling with for a while now.
Namely, I have data like:

```
[('standby', [16, 17]),
 ('unavailable', [15, 18, 19, 20]),
 ('work', [7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13])]
```

and I want to replace it with series of following numbers for each:

```
['standby', '16 - 17'],
['unavailable', '15'],
['unavailable', '18 - 20'],
['work', '7 - 10'],
['work', '12 - 13'],
```

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sasha I tried iterating over the list and comparing number with the next one, similarly to what vrachlin proposed

Comment: did i answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

very basic o(n) algorithm, pass following numbers, until they are not following, save as XX - XX then continue passing the rest until the end.

```
findFollowingNumbers (numberArr, i) :

first = numberArr[i]
while (numberArr[i] + 1 == numberArr[i+1] || i == numberArr.length - 1)
    i++
last = numberArr[i]
//save somewhere as first + " - " + last
findFollowingNumbers(numberArr, i)
```

where `numberArr = [16, 17]` for example and the first call will be `findFollowingNumbers(numberArr, 0)`